# WebRTC Javascript cannot answer on iOS

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm creating a web-app where a computer needs to communicate with another device, an iPhone XR (iOS 13). I have created the shell of the program and works fine with two computers running Chrome, but am having trouble getting it to work on the phone.

Here is the code for the 'creator' of the WebRTC server:

```html
<textarea id="creater-sdp"></textarea>
<textarea id="joiner-sdp"></textarea>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<div id="chat"></div>
<input type="text" id="msg"><button onclick="sendMSG()">Send</button>
<script>
    let id = (x) => {return document.getElementById(x);};

    let constraints = {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]};
    let pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    let dc;

    pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(e) {
        let state = pc.iceConnectionState;
        id("status").innerHTML = state;
    };

    pc.onicecandidate = function(e) {
        if (e.candidate) return;
        id("creater-sdp").value = JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription);
    }

    function createOfferSDP() {
        dc = pc.createDataChannel("chat");
            pc.createOffer().then(function(e) {
            pc.setLocalDescription(e)
        });
        dc.onopen = function() {
            addMSG("CONNECTED!", "info")
        };
        dc.onmessage = function(e) {
            if (e.data) addMSG(e.data, "other");
        }
    };

    function start() {
        let answerSDP = id("joiner-sdp").value;
        let answerDesc = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(answerSDP));
        pc.setRemoteDescription(answerDesc);
    }

    let addMSG = function(msg, who) {
        let node = document.createElement("div");
        let textnode = document.createTextNode(`[${who}] ${msg}`);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        id("chat").appendChild(node);
    }

    createOfferSDP();

    let sendMSG = function() {
        let value = id("msg").value;
        if(value) {
            dc.send(value);
            addMSG(value, "me");
            id("msg").value = "";
        }
    }

</script>
```

First, the SDP is copied from the textarea to the other 'joiner' client, and then another SDP is created which is returned to the 'creator' with the following code:

```html
<textarea id="creater-sdp"></textarea>
<textarea id="joiner-sdp"></textarea>
<button onclick="createAnswerSDP()">Create</button>
<div id="chat"></div>
<input type="text" id="msg"><button onclick="sendMSG()">Send</button>
<script>
    let id = (x) => {return document.getElementById(x);};

    let constraints = {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]};
    let pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    let dc;

    pc.ondatachannel  = function(e) {dc = e.channel; dcInit(dc)};

    pc.onicecandidate = function(e) {
        if (e.candidate) return;
        id("joiner-sdp").value = JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription);
    };

    pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(e) {
        let state = pc.iceConnectionState;
        id("status").innerHTML = state;
    };

    function dcInit(dc) {
        dc.onopen = function() {
            addMSG("CONNECTED!", "info")
        };
        dc.onmessage = function(e) {
            if (e.data) addMSG(e.data, "other");
        }
    }

    function createAnswerSDP() {
        let offerDesc = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(id("creater-sdp").value));
        pc.setRemoteDescription(offerDesc)
        pc.createAnswer(function (answerDesc) {
            pc.setLocalDescription(answerDesc)
        }, function() {alert("Couldn't create offer")},
        constraints);
    };

    let sendMSG = function() {
        let value = id("msg").value;
        if(value) {
            dc.send(value);
            addMSG(value, "me");
            id("msg").value = "";
        }
    }

    let addMSG = function(msg, who) {
        let node = document.createElement("div");
        let textnode = document.createTextNode(`[${who}] ${msg}`);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        id("chat").appendChild(node);
    }
</script>
```

This entire process works flawlessly on the computers, but for some reason cannot be done on the iPhone, even when switching the roles. Am I doing something wrong? Or could it be a feature I'm using isn't implemented yet? I've tried both Safari and Chrome on the phone.

Comment: whats not working, what errors are you getting (in browser console)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone None somehow, it just doesn't function.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yep, same exact network

Comment: I not sure, Id start by debugging all the on* events to see what's firing to get an idea of whats borked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#Browser_compatibility (see abit down the list for the on events), maybe its network maybe its something else, don't think compat issue though

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Just checked, most are unupdated, and the only that explictly not supported is ```oniceconnectionstatechange``` but that should not change anything, I tried to remove it and it still didn't work.